# Are these two forms of Hoeffding's inequality equivalent?

Tags: probability, inequality, optimization, machine-learning

Are these two forms of Hoeffding's inequality equivalent?

I am reading this https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04838 and in the paper it mentions

[image]

[image]

However, I have not seen this form of Hoeffding's inequality and I checked Shai Ben-David's textbook, the form is as such
[image]

I cannot reconcile these two forms. Are they equivalent? If so how to prove it, if not, why there are two forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by rewriting the second variant of Hoeffding's Inequality in your post (**Lemma B.6**) to use the same symbols as the symbols used in the first variant for the empirical and expected risks:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \left[ \left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| > \epsilon \right] \leq 2 \exp \left( -2n \epsilon^2 / (b - a)^2 \right).
\end{equation}

We also substituted $m$ with $n$ (to denote the number of observations).

Note that, in the Lemma from the textbook, $a$ and $b$ are the minimum and maximum values, respectively, for individual observations. In the paper you're reading, they're talking about (mis)classification probabilities, so we can take $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ (classification probabilities, or really just probabilities, will never lie outside that range). This gives

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \left[ \left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| > \epsilon \right] \leq 2 \exp \left( -2n \epsilon^2 \right),
\end{equation}

because the denominator $(b - a)^2 = (1 - 0)^2 = 1$ drops off.

Intuitively, we can read this inequality as saying "the probability that the absolute difference between the two risk quantities is greater than $\epsilon$ is less than or equal to the right-hand side". To make it more similar to the inequality from the paper, we'll try to rephrase this to something more like "with probability $x$, the absolute difference is less than or equal to some quantity". We can start doing this as follows:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \left[ \left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| \leq \epsilon \right] \geq 1 - 2 \exp \left( -2n \epsilon^2 \right)
\end{equation}

This now says "with probability greater than or equal to $1 - 2 \exp \left( -2n \epsilon^2 \right)$, the absolute difference is less than or equal to $\epsilon$":

\begin{equation}
\left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| \leq \epsilon \qquad \text{w.p. } \geq 1 - 2 \exp \left( -2n \epsilon^2 \right)
\end{equation}

Now suppose we choose to redefine $\epsilon$ as:

\begin{equation}
\epsilon \doteq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)}
\end{equation}

This then leads to:

\begin{equation}
\left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)} \qquad \text{w.p. } \geq 1 - 2 \exp \left( -2n \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)} \right)^2 \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)} \qquad \text{w.p. } \geq 1 - 2 \exp \left( -2n \frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right) \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)} \qquad \text{w.p. } \geq 1 - 2 \exp \left( - \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right) \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left| R_n(h) - R(h) \right| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)} \qquad \text{w.p. } \geq 1 - \eta
\end{equation}

In the left-hand side, the order of the subtraction of risk quantities can safely be switched around because we take the absolute value of it afterwards:

\begin{equation}
\left| R(h) - R_n(h) \right| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} \log \left( \frac{2}{\eta} \right)} \qquad \text{w.p. } \geq 1 - \eta
\end{equation}

---

This final inequality is precisely what is given in the paper, so *the conclusion is yes; they are equivalent* **given the context that the observations are (misclassification) probabilities, meaning that** $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: Isn’t the probability in the paper 1-eta?

Comment: @user136266 fixed the mistake in my answer now. When we switch from a probability that something is greater than $\epsilon$ to a probability that something is less than or equal to $\epsilon$ on the left-hand side, we have to change the right-hand side of the inequality to $1$ minus the old right-hand side.